# How to convert easily metric values to imperial using SQL or Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, converters

I'm using Crystal Reports 16 to generate reports for a customer and then use those reports in a software from another company. I'm not allowed to modify the database structure so I must do all data manipulation inside SQL Server's queries.

Most of the length in those reports are metric, but a few reports need a column with that length converted into imperial at 32th.

Here what I do in queries to convert those lengths

```
CASE
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 16 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 16 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 47 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 1/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 47 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 79 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 1/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 79 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 110 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 3/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 110 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 141 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 1/8'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 141 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 172 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 5/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 172 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 204 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 3/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 204 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 235 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 7/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 235 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 266 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 1/4'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 266 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 297 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 9/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 297 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 329 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 5/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 329 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 360 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 11/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 360 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 391 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 3/8'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 391 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 422 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 13/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 422 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 454 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 7/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 454 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 485 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 15/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 485 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 516 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 1/2'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 516 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 547 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 17/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 547 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 579 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 9/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 579 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 610 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 19/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 610 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 641 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 5/8'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 641 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 672 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 21/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 672 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 704 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 11/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 704 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 735 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 23/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 735 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 766 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 3/4'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 766 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 797 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 25/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 797 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 829 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 13/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 829 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 860 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 27/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 860 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 891 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 7/8'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 891 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 922 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 29/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 922 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION <= 954 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 15/16'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION > 954 AND a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION < 985 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES as varchar) + '"' + ' 31/32'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 985 AND a.PCE_LEN_INCHES < 11 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS as varchar) + ''' ' + CAST(a.PCE_LEN_INCHES + 1 as varchar) + '"'
        WHEN a.PCE_LEN_FRACTION >= 985 AND a.PCE_LEN_INCHES = 11 THEN
            CAST(a.PCE_LEN_FEETS +1 as varchar) + ''' 0"'
        ELSE ''
    END
```

It works ok for the amount of data I get from my query, but I use the same thing 4 times in a specific query.

In Crystal reports, I can't find any build-in founction to convert metric to imperial directly, which may improve performance much not having to do in into my query.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to convert metrics to imperials using SQL or Crystal Reports?

Comment: You could replace the entire case expression with a join to a lookup table.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create anything in the database, even for temp data.

Comment: "I use the same thing 4 times" - you can use `cross apply` to about repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

If you first round to the nearest integral multiple of 1/32 inch, you can test for numerator divisible by 32, 16, 8, 4, and 2 to reduce your case statement down to a small handful. Each case would then calculate and format your fraction as wholes, halves, quarters, etc.

Having your fraction already separated from the whole and represented as 1/1000ths complicates things a bit, especially when handling the 32/32 round up case.

Below is an example that demonstrates two versions of a more compact fraction formatter with a range of generated data.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Value Decimal(10,3),
    Inch INT,
    Thousands INT,
    ThirtySeconds INT,
    Carry INT,
    InchFraction VARCHAR(100),
    TotalThirtySeconds INT,
    InchFraction2 VARCHAR(100)
    )

-- Generate data from 0.950 thru 2.050
INSERT @Data (Value)
SELECT TOP 1101 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) / 1000.000 + 0.950
FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D1(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D2(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D3(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D4(D)

UPDATE @Data SET Inch = FLOOR(Value), Thousands = Value * 1000 % 1000

-- Calcuating from integer thousands to 32nds to fraction
UPDATE @Data SET ThirtySeconds = ROUND(Thousands * 32.0 / 1000, 0)
UPDATE @Data SET Carry = CASE WHEN ThirtySeconds = 32 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
UPDATE @Data SET InchFraction = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Inch + Carry)
    + CASE
      WHEN ThirtySeconds %32 = 0 THEN ''
      WHEN ThirtySeconds %16 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ThirtySeconds / 16) + '/2'
      WHEN ThirtySeconds %8 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ThirtySeconds / 8) + '/4'
      WHEN ThirtySeconds %4 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ThirtySeconds / 4) + '/8'
      WHEN ThirtySeconds %2 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ThirtySeconds / 2) + '/16'
      ELSE ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ThirtySeconds) + '/32'
      END

-- Calculation direct from Value
UPDATE @Data SET TotalThirtySeconds = Round(Value * 32, 0)
UPDATE @Data SET InchFraction2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds / 32)
    + CASE
      WHEN TotalThirtySeconds %32 = 0 THEN ''
      WHEN TotalThirtySeconds %16 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds % 32 / 16) + '/2'
      WHEN TotalThirtySeconds %8 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds % 32 / 8) + '/4'
      WHEN TotalThirtySeconds %4 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds % 32 / 4) + '/8'
      WHEN TotalThirtySeconds %2 = 0 THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds % 32 / 2) + '/16'
      ELSE ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TotalThirtySeconds  % 32) + '/32'
      END

-- Show summary
SELECT FromValue = MIN(Value), ThruValue = MAX(Value), InchFraction, InchFraction2
FROM @Data
GROUP BY InchFraction, InchFraction2
ORDER BY MIN(Value)

-- Show details including intermediate values
SELECT *
FROM @Data
ORDER BY Value
```

Partial Results:

| FromValue | ThruValue | InchFraction | InchFraction2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.950 | 0.953 | 0 15/16 | 0 15/16 |
| 0.954 | 0.984 | 0 31/32 | 0 31/32 |
| 0.985 | 1.015 | 1 | 1 |
| 1.016 | 1.046 | 1 1/32 | 1 1/32 |
| 1.047 | 1.078 | 1 1/16 | 1 1/16 |
| 1.079 | 1.109 | 1 3/32 | 1 3/32 |
| 1.110 | 1.140 | 1 1/8 | 1 1/8 |
| 1.141 | 1.171 | 1 5/32 | 1 5/32 |
| 1.172 | 1.203 | 1 3/16 | 1 3/16 |
| 1.204 | 1.234 | 1 7/32 | 1 7/32 |

| Value | Inch | Thousands | ThirtySeconds | Carry | InchFraction | TotalThirtySeconds | InchFraction2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.950 | 0 | 950 | 30 | 0 | 0 15/16 | 30 | 0 15/16 |
| 0.953 | 0 | 953 | 30 | 0 | 0 15/16 | 30 | 0 15/16 |
| 0.954 | 0 | 954 | 31 | 0 | 0 31/32 | 31 | 0 31/32 |
| 0.984 | 0 | 984 | 31 | 0 | 0 31/32 | 31 | 0 31/32 |
| 0.985 | 0 | 985 | 32 | 1 | 1 | 32 | 1 |
| 0.999 | 0 | 999 | 32 | 1 | 1 | 32 | 1 |
| 1.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 32 | 1 |
| 1.015 | 1 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 32 | 1 |
| 1.016 | 1 | 16 | 1 | 0 | 1 1/32 | 33 | 1 1/32 |
| 1.046 | 1 | 46 | 1 | 0 | 1 1/32 | 33 | 1 1/32 |
| 1.047 | 1 | 47 | 2 | 0 | 1 1/16 | 34 | 1 1/16 |
| 1.078 | 1 | 78 | 2 | 0 | 1 1/16 | 34 | 1 1/16 |
| 1.079 | 1 | 79 | 3 | 0 | 1 3/32 | 35 | 1 3/32 |
| 1.099 | 1 | 99 | 3 | 0 | 1 3/32 | 35 | 1 3/32 |
| 1.100 | 1 | 100 | 3 | 0 | 1 3/32 | 35 | 1 3/32 |
| 1.109 | 1 | 109 | 3 | 0 | 1 3/32 | 35 | 1 3/32 |
| 1.110 | 1 | 110 | 4 | 0 | 1 1/8 | 36 | 1 1/8 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e21d60df7401fcb6071ca95904f3369) for a demo and full results.

Disclaimer: I have not checked every transition against your original case statement, but a spot check seemed to show that you were applying a simple rounding to the nearest 1/32nd.

If you are calculating one value at a time in a function or stored procedure, you should be able to extract the intermediate calculations from the update statement. If you need to calculate the fraction values inside a query, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to build up intermediate values. Something like:

```
SELECT Value, InchFraction
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ThirtySeconds = ROUND(Thousands * 32.0 / 1000, 0)) Calc1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Carry = ...)
CROSS APPLY (InchFraction = ...)
```

What I've posted so far just deals with inch + fraction. I'll leave it to you to expand to cover the foot-inch-fraction case. Note that rounding requirements for the "x feet 11 32/32 inch" case complicates things even further. Another reason to keep the value together until all rounding is complete.

Comment: There exists edge cases where converting mm to inch, rounding to 1/1000ths and then to 1/32nds yields different results than rounding directly to 1/32nds. This is most likely to occur at odd multiples of 1/64 inch. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0feb93b2375aed436fccf8da1242f020).

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look at your boundary conditions, I now see that the mixed conditionals introduce a bias at every second boundary condition down away from the n/32ths value. A singleton bias also exists for the 0.047 case.  Duplicating this behavior mathematically would add complexity that would be less clear and more difficult to maintain.
At this point, it would be best to just use a lookup table that explicitly maps ranges of values to the desired fractional representation. The following demonstrates this approach.

```
DECLARE @FractionTable TABLE(
    LowerThousands INT,
    UpperThousands INT,
    Fraction VARCHAR(10),
    Carry INT
    )
INSERT @FractionTable
VALUES
    (000, 016, '',       0),
    (017, 047, ' 1/32',  0),
    (048, 079, ' 1/16',  0),
    (080, 109, ' 3/32',  0),
    (110, 141, ' 1/8',   0),
    (142, 171, ' 5/32',  0),
    (172, 204, ' 3/16',  0),
    (205, 234, ' 7/32',  0),
    (235, 266, ' 1/4',   0),
    (267, 296, ' 9/32',  0),
    (297, 329, ' 5/16',  0),
    (330, 359, ' 11/32', 0),
    (360, 391, ' 3/8',   0),
    (392, 421, ' 13/32', 0),
    (422, 454, ' 7/16',  0),
    (455, 484, ' 15/32', 0),
    (485, 516, ' 1/2',   0),
    (517, 546, ' 17/32', 0),
    (547, 579, ' 9/16',  0),
    (580, 609, ' 19/32', 0),
    (610, 641, ' 5/8',   0),
    (642, 671, ' 21/32', 0),
    (672, 704, ' 11/16', 0),
    (705, 734, ' 23/32', 0),
    (735, 766, ' 3/4',   0),
    (767, 796, ' 25/32', 0),
    (797, 829, ' 13/16', 0),
    (830, 859, ' 27/32', 0),
    (860, 891, ' 7/8',   0),
    (892, 921, ' 29/32', 0),
    (922, 954, ' 15/16', 0),
    (955, 984, ' 31/32', 0),
    (985, 999, '',       1)

DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Value Decimal(10,3),
    Feet INT,
    Inches INT,
    Thousands INT,
    Formatted VARCHAR(100)
    )

-- Generate data from 0.950 thru 2.050
INSERT @Data(Value)
SELECT TOP 1101 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) / 1000.000 + 0.950
FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D1(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D2(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D3(D)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) D4(D)

-- Add a few cases for carry over from inches to feet
INSERT @Data(Value) VALUES
    (118.984), (118.985), (118.999), (119.000), (119.001), (119.016), (119.017),
    (119.984), (119.985), (119.999), (120.000), (120.001), (120.016), (120.017)

UPDATE @Data
SET
    Feet = FLOOR(Value) / 12,
    Inches = FLOOR(Value) % 12,
    Thousands = Value * 1000 % 1000

UPDATE D
SET Formatted =
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.AdjustedFeet)
    + ''''
    + CASE WHEN A.AdjustedInches > 0 OR F.Fraction > ''
        THEN ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.AdjustedInches) + F.Fraction + '"'
        ELSE ''
        END
FROM @Data D
JOIN @FractionTable F
    ON D.Thousands BETWEEN F.LowerThousands AND F.UpperThousands
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        AdjustedFeet = D.Feet + (D.Inches + F.Carry) / 12,
        AdjustedInches = (D.Inches + F.Carry) % 12
) A

-- Show summary
SELECT FromValue = MIN(Value), ThruValue = MAX(Value), Formatted
FROM @Data
GROUP BY Formatted
ORDER BY MIN(Value)

-- Show details including intermediate values
SELECT *
FROM @Data
ORDER BY Value
```

Partial results:

| FromValue | ThruValue | Formatted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.950 | 0.954 | 0' 0 15/16" |
| 0.955 | 0.984 | 0' 0 31/32" |
| 0.985 | 1.016 | 0' 1" |
| 1.017 | 1.047 | 0' 1 1/32" |
| 1.048 | 1.079 | 0' 1 1/16" |
| 1.080 | 1.109 | 0' 1 3/32" |
| 1.110 | 1.141 | 0' 1 1/8" |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1.922 | 1.954 | 0' 1 15/16" |
| 1.955 | 1.984 | 0' 1 31/32" |
| 1.985 | 2.016 | 0' 2" |
| 2.017 | 2.047 | 0' 2 1/32" |
| 2.048 | 2.050 | 0' 2 1/16" |
| 118.984 | 118.984 | 9' 10 31/32" |
| 118.985 | 119.016 | 9' 11" |
| 119.017 | 119.017 | 9' 11 1/32" |
| 119.984 | 119.984 | 9' 11 31/32" |
| 119.985 | 120.016 | 10' |
| 120.017 | 120.017 | 10' 0 1/32" |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44b20378467566cd985450fd34e85b1a) for a working copy and full results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create or get a 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library) to do this. A list of 3rd-party UFLs is maintain by Ken Hamady [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

The image below shows how a simple formula expression using my CUT Light UFL handles this use case:
[image]

Comment: If the input value is metric, you can simply change the 2nd argument from "Inches" to "Millimeters".